# How to concatenate my files before feeding it to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

I have three files each having their first column as the serial number of each transaction. All I want to do is concatenate these files but I need to change the serial number in other files before concatenation but the problem is the files are way too large to write a program to concatenate these files by changing the serial number. After concatenation I want to feed this data into my Hadoop Cluster. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use MapReduce to do change the serial number names and use one reducer to output all to the same file. However, you will some how to identify the different files.

Answer (score 0):

If your source OS is Linux, you could try to use the stream editor in a sub-shell to change the serial number and pipe it into hdfs, something like:

```
(sed 's/^/1/' ./file1; sed 's/^/2/' ./file2; sed 's/^/3/' ./file3) | 
hadoop fs -put - hdfs://namenode/hadoopfile
```